# Including multiple types in Google Places API Search

Tags: python, dataframe, google-places-api, google-places

I'm trying to search the Google Places API with Python to get results for multiple types of places, but the results that I get are just those for the first type, i.e `TYPE_RESTAURANT`.

```
google_places = GooglePlaces(API_KEY)
query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
    lat_lng={'lat' : -35.28346, 'lng' : 149.12807}, 
    radius=5000,
    types=[types.TYPE_RESTAURANT] or [types.TYPE_CAFE] or 
          [types.TYPE_BAR])
```

whereas, I need the results for all three types. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

If you check the official documentation of Places API, you will find the following statement for the type parameter

> **type** — Restricts the results to places matching the specified type. **Only one type may be specified** (if more than one type is provided, all types following the first entry are ignored). See the list of supported types.

source: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests

That means you have to send multiple queries to combine several type results.